# Exclude a site from redirecting to https in apache

Tags: apache, http, redirect

We have two sites one is www.site1.com which must be redirected to https and the other site www.site2.com which is a subdomain of site1.com, should not redirected to https. we have written the following in httpd.conf file. But site2 is still getting redirected to https. Please help

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.site1.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site1.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you write anything similar (but without all the `Rewrite...` lines) for `ServerName www.site2.com`?

Comment: We have not written anything separately for www.site2.com

Answer (score 1):

`ServerName` is used to uniquely identify a virtual host, when using name-based virtual hosts.  If no matching name-based virtual host is found, then the first listed virtual host will be used. So, in your case, even if you request `www.site2.com`, the configuration for `www.site1.com` will be used, resulting in redirection.
Try adding another  section:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.site2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am sorry i forgot to mention in my post that site2.com is a sub domain of site1.com. I have tried your solution but it did not work

Comment: Does anything change if you, in your .conf file, change the order of <virtualHost> blocks (first put site2, then main site)?

Comment: If i put the site2 first then both the sites do not work. If i put site2 after site1 then site1 works but site2 doesn't work.